# Scale also in respect to vertical dimension

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
  .container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
  aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="child">
  <span style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;">right<br>side</span>
  <span style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;">left<br>side</span>
</div>
</div>

resize on bottom-right corner
```

When I resize on the x-axis (left and right) everything works exactly how I want it.
When I resize on the y-axis (top and bottom) the blue child isnt scaled anymore but overflowed?

How can I make the y-axis resizing behave exactly like the x-axis resizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `max-height: 100%` in child class

css:

```
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
  aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work with `height: 100%` but it works EXACTLY what I want with `max-height: 100%;`